# Meaning of unknown word "Steeldust"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

There is a strange usage of a strange word **steeldust**. 
It is used in the following extract from a Warhammer novel:

> ...shown in white marble numerals on their battleplates and the
>   **steeldust** rims of their pauldrons...

Googling shows that close meaning of it is an American horse breed. I am stuck on it about an hour for now!

Comment: Where on earth did you get this? Seeing it in context might help pin down what *battleplates* and *steeldust* mean. -- Is it by any chance a fantasy game of some sort? -- folks who design and write these things frequently invent non-standard terms.

Comment: From a warhammer novel. Actually context doesn't do much here.

Comment: If separated into two words, steel dust is similar to saw dust- a residue created when milling steel.  However, from context this almost seems like it's describing a color (just a guess)

Comment: What I said about games applies equally to fantasy fiction: both are set in imaginary worlds with imaginary tools and substances and social institutions, &c, for which the authors have to make up names. This isn't English, but an imagined vocabulary: you'll have to read the books to find out what the author means.

Comment: Some pattern, or a sign. 'cause numerals are in the rim of goddame steeldust

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks for a definition of a fantasy coinage.

Comment: Separately it is a real definition, wich means there is have to be proper meaning

Comment: Well, if even you can't give me an answer, then close it.

Comment: I would guess that it's referring to a color, but you've really provided insufficient context to say anything with reasonable certainty.

Comment: A guess would simply be that steeldust describes the composition and the appearance of the pauldrons, similar to diamond-plate.  Then again, it could just be an attempt at a cool sounding color, like gunmetal and ultramarine, both of which fit well into the Warhammer 40K landscape.

Comment: There's another  example in this [extract from the Warhammer novel "Storm of Iron,"](http://www.blacklibrary.com/downloads/product/pdf/s/storm-of-iron-08.pdf) on page 6, near the top of the page: "Honsou heard muffled footfalls behind him and
turned as a figure in **steeldust** armour, chevroned with yellow and
black, crept towards him." This could indicate that it means something specific in Warhammer, or it could be that these books are by the same author and that he just has an unusual preference for writing "steel dust" as one word.

Answer (score 3):

The word seems directly expressive to me. 'Steeldust' is a coinage by compounding from 'steel' and 'dust', and is used as an adjective to mean

> being, or appearing to be, coated with steel dust.

It's possible the license to coin that word was issued in error but, not having read the book nor any of the author's other works, I know nothing of the author's abilities.

Comment: Not so fresh idea, but you gave me confidence in my guesses. Thanks.

Comment: @user71305, although there's no mistake in interpreting the word as I have, I suspect there's a dimension to the word rooted in gamer esoterica which appears to have been obsoleted: see for example http://wiki.aidancbrady.com/wiki/Steel_Ingot and http://ftbwiki.org/Steel_Dust etc. This does not invalidate the immediate interpretation as a compound of steel and dust, but could augment and nuance the term for those initiated in the esoterica.

Answer (score 1):

**[Cold casting](http://www.smooth-on.com/gallery.php?galleryid=312)** commonly uses bronze dust, aluminium dust, or copper dust as a filler to give a metallic appearance to art works and museum facsimiles. The matrix can also carry a dye to give blue /aluminium, red-bronze, green patina bronze.

Steel dust or steeldust would add a range of colours from metallic grey-black, to wire-brushed wrought iron.

Hammerite paint is a plastic-based paint with a hammered steel option created with metallic dust and colouring.

Comment: I think the wery same, but i am russian, how can i know about my rightness. You all help me to make a decision. Thanks.